# android:parentActivityName doesn't work although android-support-v4.jar is included

Tags: android

i've included the android-support-v4.jar library to use "android:parentActivityName="com.myApp.example.MainActivity". It's included in "Android" Dependencies" and "Referenced Libraries", but it still doesn't work ->

> error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'parentActivityName'
>   in package 'android'

Any suggestions?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myApp.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.myApp.example.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.myApp.example.AboutUsActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/AboutUs" 
            android:parentActivityName="com.myApp.example.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.myApp.example.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The attribute `android:parentActivityName` is introduced in API 16. Set your project's build target to Android 4.1 and then you can run your app on the devices that have API level 14(you declared minimum sdk level to be 14) or higher levels if android support library is included in your project's build path.

Comment: Setting the project's build target solved this problem. Thank you!

Comment: If we use android:parentActivityName and set our project's build target to API 16, and a user runs our app with API level 14, will they encounter an error? Or does it "just work" for them?

Answer (score 47):

As @iargin said

> android:parentActivityName is introduced in API 16

It's true, and building against api level 16 works fine, however [from official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) the equivalent is using  `meta-data` tag

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.dwaik.actionbar.LocationFound"
        android:label="@string/loc">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.dwaik.actionbar.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

and it works on api level 15

Answer (score 7):

You need to add in each activity child

```
        <application ... >
...
<!-- The main/home activity (has no parent activity) -->
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" ...>
    ...
</activity>
<!-- A child of the main activity -->
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support API level 7+ -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 2):

for `android:value` may also use `android:value=".MainActivity"` because is declared the package name. `package="com.myApp.example"`

```
 <manifest  ...
   package="com.myApp.example" > 

   ...

   <activity
        android:name=".AboutUsActivity"
        android:label="@string/AboutUs" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
   </activity>

   ...

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the android:value is set to:

```
android:value="com.myApp.example.MainActivity"
```

and not:

```
android:value="MainActivity"
```

That fixed my problem.

Comment: Gradle will auto fill full name of activity class during of build