# parentActivityName not found in package android, despite using API 16 and support libs

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to work through the Android tutorial's demo app.  I'm using the command line tools, *not* Eclipse.  I've worked through to [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html), but am getting the following error when I try to run "ant debug":

```
-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [aapt] C:\Users\Vultaire\code\android\MyFirstApp\bin\AndroidManifest.xml:17:         error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'parentActivityName' in package 'android'
```

Although I really want to compile for API 15 for my Samsung S3, I'm targeting API 16 in my manifest to work around the parentActivityName errors.  The problem is, I don't seem to be getting around it.  It's like the `<uses-sdk>` tag is not being recognized.

I have API versions 14 through 17 installed, plus Android SDK tools/platform tools, and the android support library.  I've copied in the appropriate Android support library version into libs/ for eventually building for API 15.

That's all the main details I can think of, but for completeness:

My Android manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="net.vultaire.example"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="MainActivity"
                />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And my project tree looks like this:

```
MyFirstApp/
├── AndroidManifest.xml
├── ant.properties
├── build.xml
├── deploy.bat
├── libs
│   └── android-support-v13.jar
├── local.properties
├── make.bat
├── proguard-project.txt
├── project.properties
├── res
│   ├── drawable-hdpi
│   │   └── ic_launcher.png
│   ├── drawable-ldpi
│   │   └── ic_launcher.png
│   ├── drawable-mdpi
│   │   └── ic_launcher.png
│   ├── layout
│   │   └── main.xml
│   └── values
│       └── strings.xml
└── src
    └── net
        └── vultaire
            └── example
                ├── DisplayMessageActivity.java
                └── MainActivity.java
```

Thanks for any pointers...  Normally I can figure this stuff out, but I'm at wits end here.

Comment: Look at this item:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786564/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-parentactivityname-in-package-andr .

Comment: Thank you Sam.  I need to see if I can reproduce the problem.  Honestly, I retried from scratch and simply didn't try to target an earlier SDK, and it just worked...  And I haven't bothered to try targeting SDK 15 since; just hasn't been a priority.